# Track upload progress in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: vb.net, azure-blob-storage

I am building a file upload function to Microsoft Azure Blob Storage using VB.Net. Is there a way to track the progress of data transfer without using the Data Transfer Library of Microsoft? Here's my code:

```
Public Function isUploaded(ByVal filename As String) As Boolean
    Try



        Dim connectionString As String = "Connection String Here"
        Dim containerName As String = "uploads"


        Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString)
        Dim blobClient As CloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
        Dim container As CloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName)
        Dim blockBlob As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(Path.GetFileName(filename).ToString)


        Using FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename)
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(FileStream)
            Return True
        End Using


    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how many bytes have been uploaded, you can use the method [`UploadFromStreamAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlockBlob_UploadFromStreamAsync_System_IO_Stream_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_OperationContext_System_IProgress_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Core_Util_StorageProgress__System_Threading_CancellationToken_) in the sdk `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`. It will process the class [`StorageProgress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.core.util.storageprogress?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) which holds information about the progress data transfers for both request and response streams in a single operation.

[image]

For example

```
 Sub Main()
        Dim fileName As String = "D:\\help.txt"
        Dim result = isUploaded(fileName).Result
        Console.WriteLine(result)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Async Function isUploaded(ByVal filename As String) As Task(Of Boolean)
        Try
            Dim connectionString As String = ""
            Dim containerName As String = "test"
            Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString)
            Dim blobClient As CloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
            Dim container As CloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName)
            Dim blockBlob As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(Path.GetFileName(filename).ToString)
// Define the function how to handle the infromation
            Dim handelr As Action(Of StorageProgress) = Sub(progress) Console.WriteLine("Progress: {0} bytes transferred", progress.BytesTransferred)
            Dim progressHandler As IProgress(Of StorageProgress) = New Progress(Of StorageProgress)(handelr)
            Dim cancellationToken As CancellationToken = New CancellationToken()

            Using FileStream = File.OpenRead(filename)
                Await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(FileStream,
                                                       New AccessCondition(),
                                                       New BlobRequestOptions(),
                                                       New OperationContext(),
                                                       progressHandler,
                                                       cancellationToken)
                Return True
            End Using


        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
```

[image]